# GCC error: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: arrays, mplab

I'm trying to build a module table for my application.

```
/*** MODULE TABLE DEFINTION ***/ 
struct ModuleInfo
{
 char use_module;     // 0 = don't use, 1 = use, -1 for end of list
 char module_name[64];    // english name of module
 int(*module_init)(void);   // module initialization callback
 void(*module_tick)(void);   // module tick callback
 void(*module_end)(void);   // module end callback
 void *config_table;     // config table
};

/*** MODULE TABLE ***/
const struct ModuleTable module_table[] = {
 {
  1, "GPS/NMEA over RS232",
  gps_nmea_rs232_init,
  gps_nmea_rs232_tick, 
  gps_nmea_rs232_end,
  NULL
 },
 // end table
 {
  -1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
 } 
};
```

The table stores a list of modules, with pointers to initialization, tick and termination functions to be called at appropriate intervals.

I am building this using MPLAB C30, which is a version of GCC 3.23 (I think?) for specific PIC microcontrollers.

However when I try to compile this, I get:

```
In file included from main.c:3:

modules.h:67: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

The table should be const if possible because I have lots of (edit: ROM) spare and not much (edit: RAM) spare. I cannot figure out why this is not working.

Comment: What is on line 67?  What is the definition of struct ModuleTable?

Comment: Do you mean to have module_table be an array of ModuleInfo?

Comment: I believe (haven't tested) that the last initialization will put the 4 NULLs all into the first 4 elements of the 64 element char array. You would need to say `{ -1, { 0 }, NULL, NULL, NULL }` to initialize the array and then go on. In any case, that should not cause such an error message though. You don't need the `NULL` initializers explicitly either. It suffices to say `{ -1 }` for the last: Everything else will be NULL (or '\0' in the case of the char array) automatically.

Comment: @deinst please put an answer. i don't want to answer now since it looks like i stole your insights :)

Comment: @Johannes  Feel free to steal.  Someone already has.  Thanks for being honest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that is the problem...

declaring

```
const struct ModuleTable module_table[] = ...
```

is a valid C construct without defining struct ModuleTable explicitly;  which is why your code is failing, change that line to say

```
const struct ModuleInfo module_table[] = ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just a silly typo. It compiles fine now. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  -1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
 }
```

is missing a value, isn't it?  I count six fields in the struct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it didn't fix it... still same error. I thought C fills in blank values (with zero/NULL) anyway?

Comment: It probably does, or at least should.  How about having module_table[2] rather than module_table[], just in case that matters.